# Linux Bridge MAC Address flip flopping

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, mac-address

Does anybody know why our server is flip flopping between the mac address of the main network interface (eno0) and a bridge interface (br0) on the same machine.

I don't think it's affecting connectivity but I'd like to get to the bottom of it because Arpwatch is complaining every minute or so.

I'm configuring with nmcli but can edit any file by hand if need be.

Thanks very much
Andy

Comment: Can you describe your setup more? like what interface is arpwatch listening to, and what is br0 bridging to? There are different address configs for different use cases (like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319984/247007). Arpwatch should only complain if traffic coming through br0 has the same source IP address as the traffic from eno0, which would be wrong in some cases

Comment: OK, here's the setup - We have a pfsense box routing all internet traffic, this is (10.0.0.1) and is running Arpwatch and DHCP etc. The server I have issue with (10.0.0.2 on eno0) has a bridge (10.0.0.12 on br0) that we use for virtual machines connecting to a VPN. My problem is that the mac address (the one returned for the ip address of 10.0.0.2) frequently changes between the mac address of the br0 and its real interface eno0. I just can't seem to figure out why the server is sometimes returning the bridge's mac address?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It's called **ARP Flux** and exists if you have more than one network interface on the same machine with the same network subnet.

I noticed this was also happening with another server here that had 2 phyiscal cables connected to the same switch on the same subnet.

I also noticed the same problem with a Raspberry PI that had both an Ethernet connection, as well as a WIFI connection to the same subnet.

All 3 machines were constantly flip flopping their mac addresses.

So, the fix is real simple, by adding this:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1    
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce=2
```

to **/etc/sysctl.conf** and then running **sysctl -p** it fixes the problem.

I hope this helps somebody else with the same issue